# Valgrind invalid write of size 8

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm experimenting with C structs and I've come up with a `invalid write of size 8` followed by `invalid read of size 8` messages from valgrind.

My code is only looping through arguments (if `argc > 1`) and for each filename, it scans for a `string` and `unsigned int` indicating name and age(struct player).

This is all the code I've got so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct player {
  char name[20];
  unsigned int age;
};

struct player *player_new_from_stream(FILE * stream){
  struct player *new_player = (struct player*) malloc(sizeof(struct player));
  char *p_name = malloc(20);
  char *p_age = malloc(20);

  if (stream != stdin){
    if (fgets(p_name, 20, stream) != NULL){
      char *p = strrchr(p_name, '\n');
      if (p)
        *p = '\0';
      strcpy(new_player->name, p_name);
    }
    if (fgets(p_age, 20, stream) != NULL)
      new_player->age = atoi(p_age);
  }
  else {
    printf("enter name and age for a player\n");
    gets(p_name);
    gets(p_age);
    strcpy(new_player->name, p_name);
    new_player->age = atoi(p_age);
  }

  free(p_name);
  free(p_age);
  return new_player;
}

void player_inspect(struct player plyr, char* prefix){
  printf("[%s] name: %s\n", prefix, plyr.name);
  printf("[%s] age : %d\n", prefix, plyr.age);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  FILE * stream;
  char* argument;
  // below: trying to allocate (argc - 1) pointers
  // valgrind's --show-origins=yes points here for both errors
  struct player **players = malloc(sizeof(int) * (argc - 1)); 
  int i = 1;
  for (; i < argc; i++){
    argument = argv[i];
    if (strcmp("-", argument) != 0){
      if ((stream = fopen(argument, "r")) == NULL) perror("Error opening file");
      else {
        // the next line emits Invalid write of size 8 in valgrind
        players[i-1] = player_new_from_stream(stream);
        fclose(stream);
      }
    } else {
      players[i-1] = player_new_from_stream(stdin);
    }
  }

  i = 0;
  char buffer[15];
  for (; i < argc - 1; i++){
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
    // the next line emits Invalid read of size 8
    player_inspect(*(players[i]), buffer);
    free(players[i]);
  }

  free(players);
  return 0;
}
```

What is wrong here? I want to return a pointer to `struct player` from `player_new_from_stream` and pack this pointer to array `players` in `main()`.

Comment: I see someone linked why `gets` is dangerous, but what can I use to read from stdin then? Is `fgets` good for it too?

Comment: yes, `fgets()` is OK, `gets()` is *always* unsafe

Comment: What input did you test with?

Comment: two strings splitted by `\n`, that is:
`John\n40` (can't do a newline in a comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
struct player **players = malloc(sizeof(int) * (argc - 1));
```

Use this instead:

```
struct player **players = malloc(sizeof(*players) * (argc - 1));
```

Note that on your system, `sizeof(int) == 4` while `sizeof(struct player *) == 8`.

Comment: works like a charm, but why? isn't `*players` (a pointer) of type `int` or `unsigned int`?

Comment: Because `*players` is of type `struct player *` : pointer to a struct player. Here you are not allocating 4 bytes to store the pointer, you are allocating `sizeof(struct player)` bytes to store the structure data.

You should also always do `struct something *ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr));` instead of `sizeof(struct something)`. This way you're sure you have the right type, and you don't have to peer through the code if you ever change it...

Comment: In C, pointers are one kind of type, and integers are a different kind of type.  The original will work **by accident** if you run it on a 32-bit system.  Only assembly language programmers or low-level C hackers generally treat pointers and integers as the same type.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do double allocation if you want to use array:

```
struct player **players = malloc(sizeof(struct player*) * (argc - 1));
for (int i=0; i<argc-1;i++)
   player[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct player));
```

Comment: I've made a comment in the actual source code, this raises invalid write: `players[i-1] = player_new_from_stream(stream);` and invalid read comes from: `player_inspect(*(players[i]), buffer);`, source for both is here: `struct player **players = malloc(sizeof(int) * (argc - 1));`

Answer (score 1):

I ran it under valgrind with valid input files (player files), compiled with gcc -g and it didn't give any of these invalid read/write messages.

It also worked for using stdin.

However, when I ran it with non-existent files, it had a read error at

```
  i = 0;
  char buffer[15];
  for (; i < argc - 1; i++){
    sprintf(buffer, "%d", i);
    player_inspect(*(players[i]), buffer); // <<HERE
    free(players[i]);
  }
```

Since the players[i] pointer was NULL due to the pointer at that array index not being set if the fopen call fails.

Comment: Yes, my sizeof(int) == sizeof(void*), so it seems I caught a different  bug from the one Dietrich caught by his analysis.